# How to sum rows in a table based on duplicates in two columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have been googling trying to find a solution to this for two days now. I have a large dataset and want to consolidate/sum the profit rows based on the fact that they have the same ID and sale month. Example below:

```
ID  Sale Month  Profit  Person
1   5/2021           10 Tom
1   5/2021           5  Tom
1   6/2021           15 Bob
2   7/2023           20 Bob
3   5/2021           25 Jan
2   7/2023           30 Bob
```

Would ideally result to

```
ID  Sale Month  Profit  Person
1   5/2021           15 Tom
1   6/2021           15 Bob
2   7/2023           50 Bob
3   5/2021           25 Jan
```

I have tried to do powerquery groupby and pivot tables for this but I can't seem to organize it correctly. Also, after I do this consolidation I need to add a column to the dataset with an if statement that depends on the new profits, and the pivot table makes it so I can't easily do this.
The problem with groupby is I am having trouble keeping the additional columns I need (lets say product type, product color, etc) in the new combined dataset without changing the number of rows that are being combined.

For example: grouping on just the ID, month, and person results in 400 rows (which is correct)

grouping on all the columns I need (ID, month, person, type, color) results in 550 rows which implies that it is not summing how I need it do.

How do I get the type/color to show up in the new table while still summing the correct rows?

Does anyone know what I can do here? Thank you!!

Comment: I believe you would want to use the consolidate function: https://blog.coupler.io/consolidate-data-in-excel/ 
However, it's hard to tell. Can you make your examples more into a table format to make it a little more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.
You write: *"want to consolidate/sum the profit rows based on the fact that they have the same ID and sale month."*

But then you write you are grouping by *"ID, month, and person"*.

Why would you include Person if you want to group by ID and sale month.

Below is a solution to group by `ID` and `sale month`. If there is more than one person, they will all be listed in the same Person column.

If you want something else, please be more specific.

Power query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Sale Month", type date}, {"Profit", Int64.Type}, {"Person", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Sale Month"}, {
        {"Profit", each List.Sum([Profit]), type nullable number},
        {"Person", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([Person]),"; "), type nullable text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]